# Align viewport to camera in Python (inverse of align camera to view)

Tags: python, scripting, uv, 3d-view

I have 1000+ cameras and I want to unwrap my mesh UV using project from view from all of them (so creating a UV layer from each camera's project from view) so I can add a UV_PROJECT modifier for each one to texture my mesh. However, [Blender's project from view](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.uv.html#bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view) uses the current 3d view as its source. Therefore, I want to align my viewport to a selected camera before performing the project from view using Python.

How can I do this? On [Blender's Aligning page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/align.html), it provides "Align Active Camera to View" but not the inverse I need. I am new to Blender's API and workflow.

Comment: Have you tried bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()?

Comment: It worked! Right now, the background image does not match up with the UV unwrap perfectly (scaling is off) but I am pretty sure it is because I am not projecting with bounds. @Psyonic if you want you can submit an answer so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate through all objects in your .blend
If the object is of type CAMERA it gets set as the active scene camera, then the viewport is set to look through it

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == 'CAMERA':
        bpy.context.scene.camera = ob
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()
        # - YOUR CODE HERE -
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is helpful.